# Showing that a function $f$ has a fixpoint

Tags: analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

My question is how to show that the function

$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2\;,\;$ $f(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{20 \pi}\bigg(xy + \cos(xy), 1 + y^2 - \sin(xy)\bigg)$ has a fixpoint?

I know that I have to use the Banach fixpoint theorem, which I can apply because $f$ does map $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is complete, so if I can show that $f$ is a contraction, I'm done, but I have troubles to see how to show that.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mapping $f$ is not contractive in $\mathbb{R}^2$. You need to localize the solution and apply the fixed point theorem in a smaller set. For instance, from $y = \frac{1}{20 \pi}(1+y^2-\sin xy) \ge \frac{y^2}{20 \pi}$ you know that every solution satisfies $y\in[0, 20 \pi]$

Comment: @PierreCarre I don't get that. Why does that mean that the solution satisfies $y \in [0,20 \pi]$.

Comment: It means that you can restrict your analysis to a set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ for which $0 \leq y \leq 2 \pi$. If you can do something similar for $x$, you might end up with a set where $f$ is contractive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Show that the function
>
> $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2\;,\;$ $f(x,y)=\dfrac1{20\pi}\bigg(xy+\cos(xy),1+y^2-\sin(xy)\bigg)$
>
> has a fixpoint.

Yes, your function has a fixed point that is

$(x,y)=\left(\dfrac1{40},20\pi\right)\;.$

I have looked for it on the set

$\;A=\left\{(x,y):\;(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\;\land\;xy=\dfrac{\pi}2\right\}$

in order to simplify the expression of the function indeed

$\cos(xy)=0\quad$ and $\quad\sin(xy)=1\;.$

$\begin{cases}x=\dfrac1{20\pi}\big( xy+\cos(xy)\big)\\y=\dfrac1{20\pi}\big(1+y^2-\sin(xy)\big)\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}x=\dfrac1{20\pi}\left( \dfrac{\pi}2\right)\\y=\dfrac1{20\pi}\big(y^2\big)\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}x=\dfrac1{40}\\y=0\;\;\lor\;\;y=20\pi\end{cases}$

Since $\;\left(\dfrac1{40},0\right)\not\in A\;$ and $\;\left(\dfrac1{40},20\pi\right)\in A\;,\;$ your function has the fixed point $\;\left(\dfrac1{40},20\pi\right)\;.$

Comment: +1 Although you did not address the existence an uniqueness of the fixed point, that was not a requirement. You produced a fixed point and that fully answers the question.

Comment: I have just looked for a fixed point of the function on a smaller set than $\mathbb R^2$, that is the set $A.$

Comment: I ask the people, who downvoted my answer, to explain to me the reason of their downvotes.